# How to make countdown to count-up, when it reaches zero?

Tags: reverse, countdown

I try to use [this countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html). But I need to reverse it when reaches zero, e.g. when it reaches zero, it should count-up.
Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have not specified a language, so here is some java.

the algorithm still applies.

```
// the modifier to apply
int modifier = 1;

// min and max values
int maxValue = 10;
int minValue = -10;

// the value of the count
int count = 0;

// loop forever
while ( true ) {

    // it higher then max or below min
    if ( count >= maxValue || count <= minValue ) {

        // invert the modifier
        modifier = ( modifier * -1 );
    }

    // add modifier to count
    count += modifier;

    // use it
    doSomethingWith( count );
}
```

This will,

- start at *0*
- count up to *10*
- count down to *-10*
- count up to 0
- repeat